# Don't capture packets with same source and destination IP using tcpdump

Tags: linux, pcap, tcpdump

I am capturing some packets in my testing. I don't want to capture the packets with same src and dst ip. How can i achieve this?

I tried below

`tcpdump -i any '(not src host 10.10.10.10) and (not dst host 10.10.10.10)'`

The result packet capture is not satisfying. Because, I have some packets form src host 10.10.10.10 to dst host 10.10.10.20. I need to capture them.

Can someone help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
tcpdump -i any 'not ((src host 10.10.10.10) and (dst host 10.10.10.10))'
```

And if you correctly apply [De Morgan's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), the following is also equivalent:

```
tcpdump -i any '(not src host 10.10.10.10) or (not dst host 10.10.10.10)'
```

And if you append [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)'s `-d` option to both, you will see that they are in fact equivalent by the resulting compiled packet matching code.  I get the following for both:

```
(000) ldh      [14]
(001) jeq      #0x800           jt 2    jf 6
(002) ld       [28]
(003) jeq      #0xa0a0a0a       jt 4    jf 13
(004) ld       [32]
(005) jeq      #0xa0a0a0a       jt 12   jf 13
(006) jeq      #0x806           jt 8    jf 7
(007) jeq      #0x8035          jt 8    jf 13
(008) ld       [30]
(009) jeq      #0xa0a0a0a       jt 10   jf 13
(010) ld       [40]
(011) jeq      #0xa0a0a0a       jt 12   jf 13
(012) ret      #0
(013) ret      #65535
```